# Buscar Sinónimos y reemplazarlos Php, Mysql y laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo un problema un tanto complejo que estoy realizando con `Laravel`, `Php` y `MySQL`.

El usuario introduce un texto en un `textarea`, ese texto yo lo recibo en `PHP` y lo separo en palabras. Por ejemplo:

**Hola, hablar telefono.**

El texto se guarda en un arreglo así:

```
"Hola"
","
" "
"hablar"
" "
"telefono"
"."
```

Entonces el arreglo considera tanto símbolos de puntuación como espacios y saltos de línea.

Tengo una base de datos que tiene la palabra "hablar" y la palabra "telefono" en una tabla que se llama palabras. Y en otra tabla que se llama sinonimos tengo sinónimos de estas palabras relacionados por la llave foranea de la tabla palabras, por ejemplo "celular" "smartphone", etc.

Ahora, lo que yo necesito hacer es que cuando el usuario ingrese su texto, yo debo buscar cada palabra que ingresó el usuario en el textarea en a tabla palabras, para así saber si se tiene un sinónimo disponible o si la palabra existe.
Hay dos casos:
-Si la palabra existe se busca un sinónimo y se reemplaza esa palabra en el arreglo.
-Si la palabra no existe se deja esa misma palabra en el arreglo y sigue con la siguiente palabra del arreglo.

Ahora, después del proceso el Arreglo podría quedar así:

```
"Hola"
","
" "
"llamar"
" "
"celular"
"."
```

Como podemos ver se debe sustituir la palabra telefono por celular, y hablar por llamar, para después un implode y juntar el arreglo y regresar un string con el mismo texto, con los mismos espacios, los mismos saltos de línea y los mismos símbolos, es por eso que guardo también todos los espacios y símbolos para que cuando junte el arreglo se conserve la estructura del texto pero con algunos sinónimos cambiados.

El problema que tengo es que no sé como hacer la consulta de Mysql con el arreglo en Php y como hacer para ir cambiando las palabras en el arreglo de manera eficiente, por que si son 5000 palabras y se busca en una tabla que tiene 100 000 palabras debe de haber alguna carga muy fuerte de procesamiento.

¿Alguien tiene una idea de como se puede implementar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que buscas debes correr un foreach que debe quedar mas o menos asi.

```
$arregloTexto = ["Hola",","," ","hablar"," ","telefono","."];
$palabrasFinal = Array();
foreach($arregloTexto AS $palabra => $v){
    $nuevaPalabra = DB::table("palabras")
                    ->where("palabra",$v)
                    ->join("sinonimos","palabras.idPalabra","sinonimo.idPalabra")
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->get(); 

    if($palabraNueva){
        $palabrasFinal[] = $palabraNueva[0]["palabra"];
    }else{
        $palabrasFinal[] = $v;
    }
}
```

Ahora esa seria la forma mas rapida de sacarlo, si te das cuenta solo iteras sobre las palabras y las vas almacenando en un arreglo de salida, pero tiene sus problemas, tal como dices con palabras muy largas o con muchos sinonimos puede llegar a ser una carga muy fuerte al servidor, mi recomendacion es que esa parte la hagas con MongoDB, las BD no relacionales dan mucha apertura a esta clase de consultas que generan mucha presion al servidor.

Espero haberte ayudado.